# How did Madara read the Uchiha's Stone Tablet about the history?

Tags: naruto

Madara said that finding out the history of shinobi is the reason he felt hopeless and left the village. And he learned it from the Uchiha's stone tablet.

But it was said before that the Rinnegan is also needed to read what is written on the Uchiha's stone tablet. So, if Madara only awakened the Rinnegan after he left the village and his final battle with Hashirama, how was he able to read the stone tablet without the Rinnegan?

Comment: Some sort of a timeline plot hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a stretch to think that he managed to sneak back inside the village and read it in his spare time.

Somewhere before he connected himself to the Gedo Mazo and after he awakened the Rinnegan.

It is not explained however, so any answer you'll get here would be speculative.

EDIT: Now I understood your question, however, nothing told you that the part about the God Tree is only readable by the Rinnegan, maybe it was a part of the tablet that could be read using a Mangekyo.

Comment: But by the time he awakened the Rinnegan he already left the village, how can it be a reason for him to lose hope and leave the village?

Comment: This is possible but lack of proof. The manga never mentioned Madara have returned in Konoha after the fight against Hashirama.

Comment: Madara's right. If Kishi didn't create another plothole, then Madara read that God Tree part without Rinnegan. Therefore it is pretty safe to assume that Mangekyou can see the God Tree section, which also kind of makes sense since Sasuke seems to be having a different reaction than the rest of the crowd. Also, why are we questioning Madara about himself XD?

Comment: @krikara: You won't get anymore details from me.

Comment: I also thought of it as a plothole. But maybe Madara's right on Rinnegan is required only to read the whole content of the tablet. sorry about the doubt for @MadaraUchiha XD

Answer (score 0):

It's not a stretch to think that he managed to sneak back inside the village and read it in his spare time. I mean granted, he was stuck because he was attached to the statue to drain chakra from it, but that doesn't mean he forgot how to use shadow clones. That was the main point why shadow clones was invented is for recon. What the clone learned came back to the original body once the clone is canceled, no matter where the original body is, right? That's what I am thinking.